# Column Datatypes Issue in sql server 2019 when Import Flatfile using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2019

I have column in flatfile contain value like. `2021-12-15T02:40:39+01:00`
When I tried to Insert to table whose column datatype is `datetime2`.

It throwing Error as :

> The data conversion for column "Mycol" returned status value 2 and status text
> "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

What could be best datatype for such values.

Comment: *"What could be best datatype for such values."* `datetimeoffset` , likely with a precision of `0`.

Comment: @Larnu: Getting Error as : Error 0xc002f446: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "created_at" column. The binding status was "DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET". The data flow column type is "DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION". The conversion from the OLE DB type of "(null)" to the destination column type of "DBTYPE_WVARCHAR" might not be supported by this provider.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is two-fold here. One, the destination column for your value should be a `datetimeoffset(0)` and two that SSIS doesn't support the format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss` for a `DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET`; the `T` causes it problems.

Therefore I suggest that you define the column, `MyCol`, in your Flat File Connection as a `DT_STR`. Them, in your data flow task, use a derived column transformation which replaces `MyCol` and uses the following expression to remove the `T` and with a space ( ):

```cs
(DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET,0) (REPLACE(Mycol,"T"," "))
```

This will then cause the correct data type and value to be inserted into the database.